# Configuring Apache virtual hosts to run several websites on the same IP address

Tags: webserver, virtual-host

I have set up Apache Web server on my machine.

And trying to serve 2 sites for the same IP, based on the domain’s name.
I have 2 domains:

- `example0.com`
- `example1.com`

They redirect to the same ip address(I use "freenom" services)
So based on the domain name I need to provide different content.

I am following this tutorial on Digital Ocean: “[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Debian 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-7)”

I have done all steps from it, except the last one (“[Setting Up the Local Hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-7#optional-step-seven%14setting-up-the-local-hosts)”).

Result is that I get the same content for each of domain name.

I have in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`: `example0.com.conf`, `example1.com.conf`, `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf`.

In `example0.com.conf` I got:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that  
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com  

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost  
        ServerName example0.com  
        ServerAlias www.example0.com  

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example0.com/public_html
```

in `example1.com.conf` I got the same stuff but with `example1` instead of example0

I used:

```
a2ensite example0.com  
a2ensite example1.com
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you using http or https? is important to answer.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis http

Answer (score -1):

I think you are in the good direction. Check every step! it must work.

You should create two dirs for the two different webpages. Let's say:

```
/var/www/example0.com/public_html
/var/www/example1.com/public_html
```

Then you must set the owner of the dirs:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example0.com/public_html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example1.com/public_html
```

Where $USER is the owner of the apache. It depends of your system. Could be www-data, apache, http or any other. I guess on Debian should be www-data

Then make the dirs readables and executables:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Let's create a different html webpage for each (index.html in both cases):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to example0.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success, example0.com is working!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Welcome to example1.com</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Success, example1.com is working!</h1>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Save both files each one on it own dir (`/var/www/example0.com/public_html` and `/var/www/example1.com/public_html`). I repeat, both with name index.html

Then let's go to create VirtualHosts config files. Let's use as template the default file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example0.com.conf
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.com.conf
```

Then edit each one using vi, nano or any text editor software. Let's start with example0.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example0.com
    ServerName example0.com
    ServerAlias www.example0.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example0.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the same for the second file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example1.com
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, we'll activate the new sites:

```
sudo a2ensite example0.com.conf
sudo a2ensite example1.com.conf
```

Then, restart apache service to get the changes working:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And that's all.

How to test? You can change your hosts file to access to the new webservers:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   guest-desktop
111.111.111.111 example0.com www.example0.com
111.111.111.111 example1.com www.example1.com
```

Of course you must change the 111.111.111.111 ip for a real one, even your LAN ip.

Then you can test on the machine you changed your hosts file trying to access with your browser to `http://example0.com` and `http://example1.com`

Good luck!

Comment: I did the same things, when I enter different domain names the same content is returned, this is my question is about